# Finite Integer Osculations of a continuous function on a compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty compact set.  Let $f:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, so it is uniformly continuous on $K$ and bounded....Can we show that $K$ can be covered by a finite number of open subsets on which $\lceil f \rceil$ is contant?

---

So far...here is what I've thought of but I don't know where to go from here:

---

Since $f$ is continuous then each of the sets $\left\{f^{-1}(n,n+1)\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ form an open cover of $K$.  Since $K$ is compact, then there must a finite number of $n_1,\dots,n_k$ such that $\left\{f^{-1}(n_i,n_i+1)\right\}_{i=1}^k$ covers $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot show it, since it is not true. Take $K=[0,1]$ (endowed with the standard distance) and $f(x)=x$. Then $\lceil f\rceil(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$. And $\{0\}$ is not an open set.

Comment: Right, but at-least we can say that $\lceil f\rceil $ has finitely many discontinuities on $K$?

Comment: No. Take (again on $[0,1]$)$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\left|x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right|&\text{ if }x>0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\lceil f\rceil$ is discontinuous at every point of the form $\frac1{n\pi}$ ($n\in\Bbb N$).

Comment: Right, I was also thinking some modification of the topologist's curve would work.  Thank you.